How can I identify the filesystem kernel module being used for a mount?
I will give an example, so it is easier to talk, but, please, answer the main question if possible.
By what I have read, filesystems are implemented through kernel modules, which are either "embedded" into the kernel, or used separately, through .ko files -- excluding FUSE. Also, FAT has at least 2 FAT implementations: vfat.ko and msdos.ko. I would like to know the module name/filepath that is being used to mount my dev/sdc1 on /media/ABCD-EFGH.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"I would like to know the module name/filepath that is being used to mount my dev/sdc1 on /media/ABCD-EFGH" - You have only identified a device (or partition), i.e. dev/sdc1, and a mount point, i.e.  /media/ABCD-EFGH. In order to answer your question, you first need to determine what kind of filesystem exists in the device/partition that you specified. We cannot answer that for you. Have you studied the mount command?

@sawdust, I used mount, and it is "type vfat".

I would have expected more info in /var/log/syslog, but the only relevant entry I see is a sparse Aug 15 xx:xx:xx myhost udisksd[509]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/userX/DEAD-BEEF on behalf of uid 1000  "Also, FAT has at least 2 FAT implementations: ..." - Be aware that there's a third module that has shared code. See  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.10/source/fs/fat/Makefile#L6

Only a partial answer, but maybe what you are looking for.
I was digging arround for an answer to your question and came across the term "Virtual File System Switch" - sometimes abreviated as VFS.  This is the code that provides the interfaces between the filesystems and Linux.   Reading up more on this there is a file
  /proc/filesystems

Which lists out the filesystems registered with the operating system.  I'm pretty sure that the names in this "file" would map to the driver.    On my system "man filesystems" explains this, and also differentiates between msdos and vfat.  That said, the list in the man filesystems page is obviously not exclusive, because when I look onmy file server it also includes zfs and btrfs and a whole lot of other drivers also not listed.
The VFS does not need to be fuse or a module, and I'm not sure the word "embedded" is quite right - rather the code is compiled into the kernel and registered.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/vfs.html  goes into some detail as to the programing specifics.

I will try to dig into VFS. Thank you for the research, david.

Filesystem driver modules have modaliases corresponding to the filesystem name, which allows them to be auto-loaded on demand when a new filesystem is mounted.
For example, if findmnt reports that a 'vfat' filesystem is mounted, then it would have auto-loaded the filesystem driver by the fs-vfat alias, which modinfo fs-vfat will show as belonging to the vfat.ko kernel module.

That looks like the best solution! But I when I use insmod to load an external module, like simplefs.ko, then modinfo fs-simplefs does not work, but works when I do modinfo ./path/simplefs.ko. I think modinfo has some "database" for the image paths and checks it when you command modinfo <module>. Still, it should work great for non-external modules! Thank you!

The database is in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.*, generated using depmod.
